# Using Inheritance or Composition for this, or a different solution?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, composition

I have an API that I have to provide a higher level, more friendly, more streamlined framework by wrapping.

This API is already wrapped identical from its unmanaged version. But it has all sorts of unintuitive member names, workflows, etc.

I am using composition to store a reference to the underlying type that way I can have members the way I want. Basically converting and combining certain functions to properties, having higher level functionality using some other lower level logic, etc.

```
public class Effect
{
    public IEffect {get; private set;}
    ...
}
```

But one thing that I start thinking about is since the original C++ API is heavily based on inheritance and virtual methods, how should I go about "exposing"/wrapping/chaining these?

Should I just provide additional methods that calls the `internalType.VirtualMethod()`, etc? But this seems like it wouldn't work, right?

But on the other hand, if I use Inheritance myself like:

```
public class Effect : IEffect
```

then I will have all these members and weird, obsolote functions coming with it. I can still provide my higher level functionality but I don't want to show these members, because of many reasons, one of the simpliest one being they are not .NET like.

What do you suggest to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a wrapper class.  In the long term, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: Thanks but how do you mean? Using composition? Because I am already doing this. Or you mean something else?

Comment: I'd say that writing a wrapper class implies composition, not inheritance.

Comment: Yes, composition.  Take the best parts of the API and develop your own class.  If you use inheritance and expose all of the unwanted public API methods and properties, it will be difficult to undo the damage down the road.

Comment: Thanks but how am I gonna provide the virtual methods from the original types?

Comment: I don't really know what the original types are or how you plan to use them so it would be difficult to say, but the original types should be available as return types or parameters because you have to include the API with the release of your DLL.

Comment: Thanks but I can't include them as return types, right? If I do, then the user will have access to all their properties, etc. They should never have to deal with IEffect, but Effect only with some virtual methods they could override which I am trying base from IEffect.

Comment: If you don't want to give users access to the base object's return types, then you'll have to wrapper them too or add properties that return simple types.